Any way to boot a Raspberry Pi B SD card on a 4B?
I have a working Raspberry Pi 4 B and a legacy system based on an original Raspberry Pi B.  I've copied the SD card to a new microSD, but booting from it says "This board requires newer software."  Is there any way to make the new Pi boot from the old configuration?  My goal is to make a clone of the old system that's as close as possible.

You need to update /boot/firmware to include the latest. Easiest, but slightly risky, is to run sudo rpi-update.

@Dougie you can't run a command until after you successfully boot.

You can if you boot from another SD card/USB stick and mount the one that needs the update in a USB device and chroot to it's root filesystem.

This is unlikely to be possible. Raspberry Pi Ltd. recommends a fresh installation and the oldest OS that will run on a Pi4 is Buster.
Copying to an old SD (or copy) is not possible (for many reasons, including the fact that all newer OS require larger boot partition).
You can copy your home directory to a new image but you would find it simpler and faster to install new versions of any programs you want.

The problem is that I can't get the new version of the program I need to work properly.  I've tried, and so have others before me.

If you want help you need to explain WHAT "the program I need" is. Frankly many older programs have long been abandoned but there are usually better alternatives. If it is so vital, and worked on your old Pi WHY do you need to use a newer model? I still use a PiB+ on a daily basis. If you did succeed the program probably wouldn't work on newer OS/hardware.

I think you know the XY problem... Although I'd argue that it is more likely to be possible than not; the distinction between the boot firmware and kernel vs. the userland is pretty clear cut, and the former is the only thing that counts WRT  compatibility with 64-bit models (since they can run the 32-bit userland).  It might not be as simple as I presented it (eg., you may have to compile a kernel in order to get around the initramfs thing).

....I'm hazy on the significance of the kernel ABI WRT core library system calls -- they can become incompatible, but I don't think it is much of a practical reality.  That's probably the only ultimate deal breaker.

The "newer software" required is the firmware, and the OS kernel.  You should be able to use it with the old userland but I make no promises; a potential snaggle here is that new versions of the OS use an initramfs on boot which then pivots to the real root fs, but this may choke if the two are sufficiently dissimilar (dunno if that is really an issue or not).
There are two ways to approach this:

Create a new card from a new image using the normal means, then replace the root filesystem using the old card.

Copy the firmware and kernel from a new image onto the old card/copy.


An Rpi OS image produces an SD card with two partitions, the first one is a small vfat one containing the kernel and firmware, the second is a much larger ext4 one with the linux root filesystem.
First Method

Make a new card from a fresh, recent image.

Delete everything in the second partition of the new card except for the directories /lib/modules and /lib/firmware.

Copy over the old root fs. My preferred method for copying ext4 filesystems like this is:
  rsync -aHAXv --exclude=/lib/modules --exclude=/lib/firmware sourcedir/ destdir/

Where sourcedir is where the second partition on the old SD card is mounted and destdir is the same from the new card. Don't leave off the trailing slashes.


If you do have a Pi that the old card currently works in, don't use it to do this.  It's possible, but using a running system introduces some complications that I won't address here.
Second Method
This is the inverse of the above, more or less.  You don't need to create a card from the new image though, you can instead just mount it if you like.  You'll need to access both partitions.

On the old card or copy thereof, delete everything on the first partition.
Copy everything in the first partition from the new image into the first partition on the old card.
Delete /lib/firmware and /lib/modules from the second partition of the old card.
Copy everything from the same two directories of the new image onto the old card.

Important!
Regardless of which method you use, you'll have to edit cmdline.txt in the first partition of the hybrid card. It should remain all one line, no breaks, just spaces.

Remove init=/usr/lib/raspberrypi-sys-mods/firstboot.

In this bit:
  root=PARTUUID=617a2abd-02 

Change the 617a2abd to the real partuuid of the card; you can get that by running, eg., blkid /dev/sda, where /dev/sda is the card.


